# mongoDB: check if existing nested object in document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need a find query, which is searching for an existing attribute in an array.

If this is the document...

**document**

```
{
    id: '123',
    attr: 'anything',
    author: [
        { id: '1' },
        { id: '2' }
    ]
}
```

... I want to check if there is a document with an author id existing:

**find query**

```
var id = '123';
var uid = '2';

Collection.find({ _id: id, author: { id: uid } })
```

This should give me one result.

If `uid = '3'` there would be no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ["dot notation"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to denote embedded fields:

```
Collection.find({ "_id": id, "author.id": uid })
```

Otherwise you are asking for a document that has "exactly" and only a single object with the requested value. This just asks "does one possible value match".